# fluentd re-tag events based on log containing a string

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd

We collect json logs with fluentd (to ES) from a source that has multiple types of logs that are all json but have different structure.

I would like to re-tag logs that contain certain strings in any of the keys.

If the keys that would contain this string would be limited, rewrite tag filter would do the job but since the structure of the logs is so different (and in the future new logs structures might appear) would be nice if there was a way to scan every key or better yet just check the whole content of the log rather key based (if that would improve performance).

Is there any way to achieve this at the moment?

Comment: Can you please provide fluentd conf with what you have tried so far?.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter